# Help me on Payments and Financial Reports

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, app-store-connect

I have uploaded my iPhone app and it is available for sale in the app store...

what i need to know is i am charging the user for sending the digital content.

and now i have downloaded and installed my own app into my device for checking my in app purchase.

I want to know where i can see my financial transaction ( i mean the earnings by sending the digital content )

I checked this Payments and Financial Reports in the iTunes Connect portal.

but my earnings shows "there are no reports that match your request."

Plese help where i can see my in app purchase transaction earnings....

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going through Apple for in-app content, iTunes Connect should have all of your financial information. However, if the transactions are less than 30 days, they may be inaccurate.

When you login to iTunes Connect, look for `Payments and Financial Reports` and you will see your Earnings, Whats Owed to you, and past payments to you by Apple.